# How to list the most expensive and least expensive price of items (SQL)

Tags: sql, list

I wish to find the solution to being able to list the price of my most expensive items and least expensive items. The most basic of solutions would be very helpful.

Kind regards,

C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  look at this first

Comment: What does your table look like? Names (table + columns)? Have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Here.

```
Select TOP (10) I.Price [Most expensive price]
from Items as I
order by I.Price DESC

Select TOP (10) I.Price [Least expensive price]
from Items as I
order by I.Price ASC
```

Comment: I would use `TOP(1)` for the most one, instead of `TOP(10)` ;)

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon Well, the question does say "most expensive **items**", plural meaning more than one. 10 might be a bit too many, depends on how many items they actually have.

Comment: Sorry, i have not noticed the S, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `item` and your columns are called `name` and `price` the following query would do the trick if you want the most expensive item first:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item 
ORDER BY price DESC
```

To query the cheapest item first:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item 
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Order By](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CE8QFjAE&url=http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-clause.htm&ei=VrXXUujcM8Orrge9l4G4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGf3ofBgF1jJT88FOEh8y5JlJOCKw&bvm=bv.59568121,d.bmk) clause to find the solution:

```
select * from Table Order By Price DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the very best way to ask a question - Did you try anything ? If you are new, did you research anything ? Anyway, assuming that your table has a `price` field, you could use something like this -

```
SELECT
    MAX(price) AS [MOST EXPENSIVE],
    MIN(price) AS [LEAST EXPENSIVE]
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
WHERE YOUR_CONDITION_IF_ANY
GROUP BY YOUR_GROUPING_IF_ANY
```

Comment: It says "most expensive itemS" and "least expensive itemS"

Comment: Just like anyone can assume 10 (or N) most/least expensive items, I assume **bad English** - and somehow I feel my assumption would be closer to reality. If you have 10 items in your table - and you select 10 most & least expensive items - Doesn't the MOST expensive become the one of the LEAST expensive as well? Hence my assumption - **bad English**.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the record for max and min price.

```
select * from test
where price in (select MAX(price) from test) 
OR price in(select MIN(price) from test)
```